# Socle of socle of module is the socle of the module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let M be any left R-module.

I'm having problems proving that
$$ Soc(Soc(M)) = Soc(M) $$

Where $Soc$ is the socle of the module defined as:

$$ Soc(M) = \sum \{V \ \subseteq  M\  |\text{$V$ is a simple left $R$-module}\}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The socle is always a semisimple module, and the socle of a semsimple is always the entire module…

Answer (score 1):

I write $SM$ for the soccel of $M$. It is clear that $SSM \subset SM$. Now take $x\in SM$. The element $x$ may be written as a finite linear combination $x=y_1+ ...+y_n$ where each $y_r$ is contained in a simple submodule $V_r$ of $M$. But each $V_r$ is also a simple submodule of $SM$, so in particular $y_r$ is contained in $SSM$. Since $SSM$ is a submodule, it follows that $x$ is contained in it.